# android studio, кластеризация маркеров

Tags: android

скажите,пожалуйста, как подключить android maps extensions в android studio, чтобы с ней начать работать?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно нашел библиотку по названию, то просто добавьте это
`compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'`
в файл **build.gradle** в раздел **dependencies** и будет вам счастье

**UPD:**
Я бы посоветовал вот эту библиотеку: [Google Maps Android API utility library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/).
[Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/224889/) рассказано как ей пользоваться

Comment: я это пробовал,но что-то не получилось или я не правильно подключал